# Using Amazon Simple Workflow SWF on Non-Amazon Servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I've read in the documentation that SWF can be used 'on-premise'.  Does that mean SWF can be used on a private company server farm or another cloud computing provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no...yes, you can use SWF to implement a workflow on your on premises hardware (or another provider), but SWF itself still runs on AWS - your applications make calls to SWF, those calls are answered by SWF running on AWS. The work those tasks do however you can run where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-develop-activity.html .
It says "Activity workers are managed by you. They can be written in any language. A worker can be run anywhere, as long as it can communicate with Amazon SWF through the API."